# wxpython rearrange bitmap on resize

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I have this wxpython code, where I am displaying image along with text. I am using flexgridsizer for layout management. I want when I resize the window, images should reshuffle as per the size like if there is more room than the column and row should expand, also I see flicker while regenerating images.

Please suggest, if there is anyother better way to do this

```
import wx

ID_MENU_REFRESH = wx.NewId()
#dummy description of image
imglist =['One','Two','Three','Four','Five','Six','Seven','Eight','Nine','Ten']

class Example(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        mb = wx.MenuBar()
        fMenu = wx.Menu()
        fMenu.Append(ID_MENU_REFRESH, 'Refresh')
        mb.Append(fMenu, '&Action')
        self.SetMenuBar(mb)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.refreshApps, id=ID_MENU_REFRESH) 

        #storing the thumb image in memory
        self.bmp=wx.Image('img/myimg.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap()
        self.panelOne = wx.Panel(self)        
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.panelOne.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.panelOne.Layout()
        self.myimg_holder={}
        self.showThumb(imglist)
        self.SetTitle('Example')
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def refreshApps(self,event=None):
        #remove 
        self.showThumb()
        #repaint
        self.showThumb(imglist)

    def showThumb(self,thumblist=None):


        if not thumblist:
            for child in self.panelOne.GetChildren(): 
                child.Destroy() 
            self.myimg_holder.clear()
            self.panelOne.Layout()
            return 

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer()
        gs = wx.FlexGridSizer(8, 6, 10, 20)
        #blank text holder for padding
        gs.Add(wx.StaticText(self.panelOne),flag=wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, border=2)
        vzis = []
        for num,app in enumerate(thumblist):
            vzis.append(wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL))
            appid = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panelOne,wx.ID_ANY, self.bmp, (5,5), (self.bmp.GetWidth()+5, self.bmp.GetHeight()),name=app.strip())
            vzis[num].Add(appid,0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
            self.myimg_holder[appid]=app
            vzis[num].Add(wx.StaticText(self.panelOne,-1,app),0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER,border=1)
        for i in range(len(thumblist)):
            if i in [4,8,12]:
                gs.Add(wx.StaticText(self.panelOne),flag=wx.ALL, border=2)
                gs.Add(wx.StaticText(self.panelOne),flag=wx.ALL, border=2)
                gs.Add(vzis[i],flag=wx.ALL, border=1)
            else:
                gs.Add(vzis[i],flag=wx.ALL, border=1)
        vbox.Add(wx.StaticText(self.panelOne),flag=wx.ALL, border=4)
        vbox.Add(gs, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL)
        vbox.Add(wx.StaticText(self.panelOne),flag=wx.ALL, border=4)
        self.panelOne.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.panelOne.Layout()

def main():

    ex = wx.App()
    frame = Example(None)
    frame.Show()
    ex.MainLoop()    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the images to rearrange themselves, then you don't want to use the FlexGridSizer. What you want is the WrapSizer:

- http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/WrapSizer.html
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/01/22/wxpython-wrap-widgets-with-wrapsizer/

If you want the bitmaps themselves to resize when you're resizing the frame, then you'll have to do that yourself. The sizers don't do that automatically. They do resize normal widgets, but not images. You would probably need to catch EVT_SIZE and resize the bitmaps as appropriate if you wanted to go that route.

To reduce flicker, you'll probably want to take a look at the Freeze and Thaw methods.